# PPoE forwarding on pfSense

Tags: networking, router, pfsense, pppoe

(reposting from NETGATE PfSense forum)

Basically I'd want the PfSense to forward PPoE packets that come from an host on the LAN side of the pfsense to the main ISP router (so that I can get a public IP).
This is a map of the network:
[image]

N.B. The link I want to create is virtual, meaning that there is always physically the pfsense between those two routers.
The PfSense manages to get a public IP using PPoE on the WAN interface (and it works great) but now it's time for the Fritz to also have a public IP (keep in mind that it is connected to the LAN side of the PfSense) and that's why I need the pfsense to simply forward (I think “passthrough” would be te correct term) the ppoe traffic.
The PPoE “server” is my ISP (strange but true I can establish “unlimited” ppoe connections and get “unlimited” public (dynamic obviously) IPs. 
Anyone has some idea?
(I'd prefer not to change the physical configuration of the network because I have particular needs but if there is no viable option I could decide to change that).

Comment: Why don't you set up **two** public IP addresses on pfSene via PPPoE and do unconditional forwarding from one of those to fritz?

Comment: The reasoning behind that is, that PPPoE discovery packets can not be used (to set up the pfSense IP) and unconditionally forwarded to Fritz at the same time.

Comment: Mmm looks interesting, so if I decide that i dont want anymore the PPoE IP on the PfSense (so it will get a private class address from the main ISP router, something like 192.168.1.100) and get the PPoE public IP only on the Fritz? Could this be done?

Comment: I don't know your ISP's setup, but you could route **all** PPPoE packets through pFsense to the Fritz

Comment: I know all the info for the ISP connection, the problem is "how to make the pfsense forward the PPPoE traffic", even as you said all the traffic. I couldn't find anything on the web.